# How many Vaults are in Fallout 4 and what were their purposes?

Tags: fallout-4

How many Vaults are in Fallout 4 and what were their purposes?

I know that Vault 111 was used to test the effect of cryogenics on unaware dwellers, but are there other Vaults in the wasteland, and if so, what were their purposes (or the experiments conducted in them)?

So far I've found 4 other vaults, Vault 114, 75, 81, and 95.  I am having issues finding out what exactly Vault 95 was for (as the terminals there show no info), and am trouble finding out what else the others were for. Are there also additional vaults that I missed in this list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Fallout wiki](http://fallout.gamepedia.com) has an [extensive list of known Vaults, as well as their purpose](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/List_of_known_Vaults). Each vault description is backed by in-game material you are suppose to look for, but it does appear to confirm that there are no other vaults to be found as of yet.

---

- **Vault 75**: Vault 75 is an experiment in improving the human genome. It appears these tests were carried out using selective breeding, genetic modification and hormonal treatment. The test subjects have their growth accelerated, and at 18, are "disposed of". It is suggested that in certain situations, such as for the purpose of replacing research staff, exceptional candidates may have been used for other means.
- **Vault 81**: Vault 81 is a testing facility involving antibodies, disease and radiation. Vault 81 was under express orders to not evacuate under any circumstances, unless an official "all clear" was issued. In the event of an evacuation, it is suggested that the overseer would order the 'dweller section' to be mass-incinerated, including the dwellers.
- **Vault 95**: Vault 95 is a social experiment on isolation and drug addiction. All dwellers were drug addicts, and the experiment started pre-war.
- **Vault 111**: This is the vault our hero comes from, and was a test in cryogenics and long-term suspended animation.
- **Vault 114**: Vault 114 was another social experiment, where the inhabitants consisted almost entirely of upper-class society. The living conditions of the vault was advertised as highly luxorous, but in reality, it was the exact opposite. The overseer was chosen from the general population, and the interview process favored qualities such as no leadership skill and issues with authority. The purpose is listed in a terminal; "By taking away the luxury and authority these groups saw in surface life, we hope to study their reactions in stressful situations."

Comment: Neat, thanks! Although I'm curious, where did you get the info on Vault 95? I explored every nook and cranny in there and couldn't find any information on what happened in the vault.

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m If you have Cait as a follower she eventually tells you a little bit about what she's heard of vault 95. That's most likely where the information in the wiki came from. Edit: I read timelord's comment after posting mine, I can personally confirm though that the information about 95 is correct.

Comment: Still sounds a bit more reliable, @VanBuzzKill.

Comment: @Timelord64 I finally made it to the vault. After you enter, there is a staircase to the right that leads to some rooms. There are 2-3 terminals with plenty of information in some of the rooms. The basics are that one of the vault dwellers was an insider with vault-tec. His job was to wait 5 years so the dwellers can detox and "become a family", then expose a hidden chems stash within the vault to see the reaction of the dwellers

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to answer the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

They are talked about in the terminals. States they were weened off drugs, then after five years they were re introduced. It's why it's mayhem everywhere in it.

Comment: Which vault are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

To better clear up the Vault 95 issue (SPOILERS AHEAD for all those not wanting to know).

The vault was a test in weening people off drugs. There would be group meetings and the Overseer would be selected annually as a sort of "group leader", who the others would rely on for the most support. All but one of the members was an addict. This secret member was a Vault-Tec employee, who knew the location of a secret stash of drugs (described in another terminal to "last a lifetime") and would unlock this stash in 5 years, and just leave it to be found.

After the 5 years notes show clear progression from many people, but the moment drugs are re-introduced, some grabbed what they could and ran to get high, while one individual barricaded himself in his room, his personal terminal showing a slow progression of wanting the drugs, and how the outside is affected. The Vault-Tec employee is assumed to have died quickly, as he was ordered to make weekly reports after revealing the drugs, but only ever made a single report stating he was about to unlock the stash.

#### Some notable things about vault 95

The room with the terminal of the man recording the chaos outside, and mentions barricading himself in, has a wall that was clearly broken through from the inside. With his door still blocked, this shows he literally broke down a steel reinforced wall to "be with his friends in his final moments".

The Overseer's room is clearly where people met for their anti drug meetings, however, skeletons are also found here, suggesting that in their final days, the remaining living members (after gunshots were heard) came to this room, and overdosed together.

Comment: Ok, seriously... all these information seems to be IN GAME, and I don't remotely see the need for asking the question on SE at all...
I don't have Fallout 4 yet, but in 3 and NV, all the vaults always explain what they were for, **if you played the game instead of trying to ask questions for rep on SE**.

Comment: Irrelevant. Stackexchange is about asking questions. Nobody is forcing you to read them. All questions (that fit the site's profile) are welcome.

Comment: There is a companion quest that takes you to Vault 95, but saying any more than that is spoilerific.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Vault Tech HQ you can find a lot of the info on vault 95 and you sort of predict what happens there. Along with terminals within the vault that tell you exactly what goes on and how they ran everything. Most of the info about vaults is learned through the terminals though.